# Flutter: How to install new pod after modify plugin's podspec?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

There is a plugin in my project named `zendesk`:

[image]

For some reason I would change it's `podspec` file to dependency a new SDK:

[image]

**How to install this new SDK?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `flutter clean`, then execute `run`, the pod would install automatically.